# Backlog multi appender with different level

Tags: logback

How can I log everything to WARN to a file and the console, but `my.package` to DEBUG only for file?

I tried:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <File>target/log/test-log</File>
        <append>false</append>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="my.package" level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="my.package" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But it would log everything to DEBUG in the console too.

This also doesn't work:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <File>target/log/test-log</File>
        <append>false</append>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="io.chumps">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" level="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" level="WARN" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using `GEventEvaluator` with custom Groovy scripting:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#GEventEvaluator

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LAYOUT" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n" />

    <root>
        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
                <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
                    <expression>e.level.toInt() >= WARN.toInt()</expression>
                </evaluator>
                <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
                <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>${LAYOUT}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
                <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
                    <expression>
                        e.level.toInt() >= WARN.toInt() ||
                        (e.level.toInt() >= TRACE.toInt() &amp;&amp; e.getLoggerName().startsWith("my.package"))
                    </expression>
                </evaluator>
                <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
                <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>${LAYOUT}</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <File>target/log/test-log</File>
            <append>false</append>
        </appender>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I can't believe this so simple usecase is not supported by default.